# My sarcastic comment was deleted! I feel betrayed!

Tags: discussion

No not really `;-)`

But still, [when the question asks for it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23369737/will-my-dev-iphone-expire-for-development-purposes-the-way-my-old-mac-did), can't some sarcasm be allowed? I think sometimes, the absurdity of a question requires some sarcasm to let the asker know that his question is absurd. "Will my hardware age?" - Well *gosh darn it*, no! Just downloads updates from the internets!

Comment: Sarcastic comments tend to come across much more unfriendly than they were originally intended through the anonymous pipes of the Internet. A strong case can be made for deleting them wholesale for that reason, even though many of them were written with no malicious/abrasive intent at all.

Comment: No sarcasm is allowed. Ever.

Comment: When people go up in the SO ranking they sometimes tend to get unfriendly and with the wrong spirit of "I'm too good to answer that question". I feel that every question should be taken seriously, even if very naive and answered with the best possible effort.

Comment: @Matteo No; in fact that's contrary to the mission of SO.  Every question should *not* be answered.  Only questions that meet the site's (rather high) standards should be answered.  (Either that or you're being sarcastic, which I really hope you are, but that doesn't seem likely.)

Comment: Every question that is *clear, answerable and on-topic* deserves attention.  Not all questions meet this metric.

Comment: I think my sarcastic ploy was successful - bringing attention to a bad question. =]

Comment: You forgot to include the maniacal laugh.

Comment: Muaha ... muaahahahahah.

Comment: Oh sure, more sarcasm is what we need.

Comment: Apposite sarcasm, when coupled with wit or insight, can be a delight.  There have been several times when actually giggled.  I would hate to see it banned.  Of course in moderation, with gentleness, not all the time, etc etc etc etc

Comment: Instead put up a usefull comment as to why you close voted so the new user can improve his question or do better next time. That is what every close- or down-voter should do, help out the community.

Comment: About that question, is it really that terrible? They're asking about obsolescence of development devices, and I can understand where they're coming from. Is it necessary to mock someone asking a question like that? That seems a little harsh.

Comment: Sarcasm on SO sites is a complete waste of everyone's time (the sarcasm creator as well as the receiver). This is not TMZ.com or PerezHilton.com.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> But still, when the question asks for it, can't some sarcasm be allowed?

We don't spend a lot of time looking at the context around an obviously sarcastic comment before deleting it. It's not that moderators are anti-fun, we just don't have the time to read every question to decide if the OP was *really* asking for it.

Comment: I up voted this answer, but I feel a clarification is in order; *"It's not that moderators are anti-fun"* should be changed to *"It's not that moderators are all|necessarily anti-fun"*